# Varagant up command showing error in windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant

While using vagrant up command in windows 10, I am getting the following error

```
Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Operation canceled by the user
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

A [proposed answer](https://codias.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/vagrant-on-windows-10-error-when-you-run-vagrant-up/) is

> 1. Open VirtuaBox
> 2. Go to File->Preferences->Network->Host-only Networks
> 3. Create Manually a new adapater like as follow:
>
> IPv4: 192.168.2.1 (in my example my vm ip is 192.168.2.2 you must use the 3 first parts
> equal as your ip address and replace the last one by 1)
>
> Mask: 255.255.255.0